# getting the text from an WebElement

Tags: java, xpath

Say I have an element (doesn't really matter what.  Let's say "//div[@id='tony']/div/span" but any xpath would be OK.

To get the text on a page from this you could do something like

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='tony']/div/span"));
System.out.println(ele.getText());

// Or an our system someone wrote a method so we can get all text in that
// element and everything underneath (part of that element)
System.out.println(getText(ele));
```

This is fine when you are running the program.  But originally when you are writing and debugging with Chrome before you actually write the program.  In Chrome you can do right click -> inspect and then in the bottom do a ctrl-f which opens a search box and you can type an xpath and it will highlight it (them) on the page.

Now I swear several months ago when I was debugging I could also have it display the text in that element but I don't remember how?  You type something into the search box like get-text(//div[@id='tony']/div/span) but I can't remember or figure it out.  Perhaps at the time I was using Firebug and not Chrome?

Does anyone know a way to have it print the text of the element?  I know you can eyeball it in the HTML code but what you think is the text and what it actually is is not always the same

Comment: you waht something like `//div[@id='tony']/div/span/text()` ?

Comment: That finds the elements but does not print the contained text